# REGEX NOTEPAD ++

Tags: regex

I have a list in this format

```
FIRSTTEXT:SECONDTEXT:RANDOMTEXT::::::::RANDOMNUMBERS:NUMBER:
```

but all the text is not in this format. i want to save only FIRSTTEXT:SECONDTEXT,
firsttext and secondtext are in the same position on all document !

I have tried this one:

**Find what**: `(.+):(.+)`
**Replace with**: `\1:\2`

However, it doesn't work.

Comment: i want to clean all the other text except Firsttext:secondtext

Comment: `.+` is greedy; Try `.+?`

Comment: Try `^(?:([^:\s]+:[^:\s]+).*|.*\R*)`, replace with `$1`

Comment: Wiktor stribizew thank you works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**:  `^(?:([^:\s]+:[^:\s]+).*|.*\R*)`
**Replace With**: `$1`

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `([^:\s]+:[^:\s]+)` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to this value):

    - `[^:\s]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `:`
    - `:` - a colon
    - `[^:\s]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `:`
  - `.*` - 0+ chars other than any line break char, as many as possible
- `|` - or

  - `.*` - 0+ chars other than any line break char, as many as possible
  - `\R*` - 0+ line break sequences
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group.

Demo and settings:

[image]